# Demo of designing a modern CPU in Verilog/VHDL

Tags: integrated-circuit, vhdl, verilog, vlsi

Please help me understand how such huge and complex devices like modern CPUs' are designed - would it be possible to see an example of some final circuit with billions of transistors made with Verilog/VHDL? All examples on the Internet show only small ICs. I would like to see how today's engineers manage "ultra-large-scale integration" designs for chips like CPU/GPU/ASIC on regular workstations. I would like to know how such humongous device can be managed effectively and by so many people.

I am aware of FGPAs, but I think that their workflow is much more predefined and doesn't lend itself to the same complexity. I am aware of the Verilog/VHDL pipeline and I haven't seen anywhere a demonstration with BILLIONS of transistors chips.

I would really like to know how teams manage such amount of complexity and how much is it being broken down into IP blocks. For example, how many lines or Verilog/VHDL is being written for one of Intel's i7 CPUs?

RISC-V looks interesting and if nothing was available on the mainstream ICs it would be also helpful to see some good CAD/GDS output from RISC-V.

The reason why I would like to see it, is I worked a lot with CAD software (AutoCAD, McNeel's Rhino) and it's always been very slow. Hope that getting some insight from EDA/ECAD could hint a path to use them more effectively.

Comment: If you browse the schematic of even an ordinary interface IP, like GMAC or USB, you'll find yourself sunken in a sea of gates.

Comment: There are many opensource core designs available that you can look into the guts of. However, if you want something that once was in real production, Oracle has actually released the Verilog source code and design docs for their UltraSPARC (OpenSPARC) [T1](https://www.oracle.com/servers/technologies/opensparc-t1-page.html) and [T2](https://www.oracle.com/servers/technologies/opensparc-t2-page.html) processors. They are both over a decade old, but still actual multicore "SMT4" designs. If you are looking for the "masks" for a large CPU like that, I doubt you'll find anything like that public.

Comment: @Light thank you, I think that part of my problem is not knowing what keywords to look for. Thats helpful

Comment: @Light would it be possible to see somewhere, maybe in some older model a complete assembled chip as well?

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat I see, that makes sense. Thanks for mentioning OpenSPARC, I will take a look at it. I am not very familiar with this chip and I hoped to learn from something closer to today's CPUs/GPUs though.

Comment: @DanielKrajnik I remember that once I read reports about the successful reverse engineering of 8051 and a Russian made x86 compatible CPU. But I've no idea where can find the source code now. And if it really exists, I doubt if they are *complete* (a full chip design including IOs and any potential hardened macros).

Comment: Depending what you mean by "see", https://zeptobars.com/en/ has a lot of *die shots* for "complete assembled chips" that have been *decapped* so the metal+silicon can be seen.

Comment: @pjc50 haha "see" as in CAD/vectors drawings. I have often come across a problem were building models were so big that they had to be split into two, just to be able to work in them - knowing that chips are even bigger I wanted to see if "foundries" solved it better.

Comment: @Light awesome, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think such large ICs are designed directly in Verilog, no more than large software projects are written in assembly. I suspect the big makers, like Intel and AMD, have specialist compiler-like software that generates Verilog from much more high-level descriptions, such as register transfer languages.

Comment: interesting, it would be so helpful to know what "tech stack" / tooling Intel and AMD has. Importantly, do you think they have a normal repository like Perforce, or more something custom like Google did?

Comment: And also do you think that any part of the circuit is still drawn by hand or is EVERYTHING generate by code (RTL or Verilog)?

Comment: No idea, but I don't see why they wouldn't be satisfied with Git. Re drawn by hand, again I have no real idea, but the lower-level power-related stuff seems like a plausible candidate for that.

Comment: AFAIK only the higher-level floor planning (and I suppose the standard cells) are "drawn by hand", the rest is all automagic as far as typical digital designs are concerned. Not that I know anything about this though, just what I might've heard once; so all of this comment might be completely mislead. Please correct me.

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat interesting, and woud you be able to point me to some source to read more about how today's "automagic" works, by any chance?

Comment: @AntonTykhyy last time I did contract IC design the version control tool used was something much, much worse than git; a weird proprietary thing whose name I've forgotten. The size of the files involved, especially intermediate binaries, can make ordinary vcs software a problem.

Comment: Automagic keywords are "place and route", maybe? This lecture seems to hit most of the key points https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee290c/sp18/lec/Lecture12A.pdf

Comment: Today's CPUs are not really CPUs but SOCs containing *many* different CPUs. And most of the work packing and interconnecting the *existing* IPs in the most efficient way.

Comment: @EugeneSh. exactly, that was my impression as well. Parts like Intel's ME is for example equally fascinating and enigmatic. Is it possible to know even approximately how many IPs are there and what's their overall layout.

Comment: @pjc50 perfect, thanks!

Comment: @pjc50 interesting, I guess that the main driver to choose such proprietary vcs are file sizes...

Comment: @DanielKrajnik Well, this is not impression, but a knowledge :) Unfortunately can't share to much of it. But I can tell you that there are tens of complex IPs, some of these are developed in-house, some are off-the-shelf/customized/provided by partners, and there are literally thousands of people involved in the development and there is no single person that knows *everything*.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the tech stack (knows as a *flow*) tends to be a trade secret and heavily NDA'd.

As a beginner asking an open-ended question, perhaps the most useful answer is a list of places to look for more information. The two big software vendors are Cadence and Synopsys. Both of them offer a full flow from RTL (and earlier) through to the polygons sent to the foundry ("GDSII" pronounced "G D S two", it's a file format). They produce [lots of brochureware with pretty diagrams.](https://ip.cadence.com/knowledgecenter/know-ten/eda-flow)

> I would really like to know how teams manage such amount of complexity and how much is it being broken down into IP blocks. For example, how many lines or Verilog/VHDL is being written for one of Intel's i7 CPUs?

Quite a lot of the larger chips is on-chip SRAM, which adds a lot to transistor count while not appearing as very complex in the design phase. Similarly, things like GPUs have lots of identical execution units. Design once, paste lots of copies across the chip, then put a tie layer across the top.

Intel themselves will occasionally put out whitepapers and presentations in which they show block diagrams.

> The reason why I would like to see it, is I worked a lot with CAD software (AutoCAD, McNeel's Rhino) and it's always been very slow

I have some bad news for you: I worked on some EDA software about a decade ago, and it was also incredibly time-consuming. Our startup offered a tool that would adjust your clock tree to reduce power by 10-20%. For a million gate design on the largest PC we could buy at the time it ran *overnight*.

Back then larger designs were generally broken down into 1m-gate sized blocks at the "floorplanning" stage, on the basis of what the team and tools were capable of managing.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for shedding light on performance, copy-paste strategy issues and the rest - very helpful. That's really heartbreaking that we put up with this workflow, this may sound spoiled coming from me, but I think that need for "instant gratification" is actually a virtue. Do you know if there have been any improvements since then, any new software frameworks that might have turbo-charged the workflow?

Comment: It's a very small, conservative, uncompetitive market - there will have been incremental improvements, but no big disruptors. I think alternative HDLs like Chisel are starting to make inroads but the low level tooling remains as it is. Perhaps eventually an open FPGA toolchain will appear on which rapid public progress can be made.

Comment: that would be great, fingers crossed. Hmm, and yes that's actually a really good point.